# Поменять стили при наведении на блок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть такой блок

```
<div class="top-bar">
</div>
```

Такие стили

```
.top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity:1;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 99; 
}
```

Это Header. Он зафиксированный. Как сделать так что бы при скролле вниз, у него становилось свойство `opcity:0.5`, а при наведении на него `opacity:1`;

Comment: так у `.top-bar` и так `opacity:1;` а что делать, если элемент не скролится и на него не навели мышкой? :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    e = $('.top-bar'); // кэшируем элемент, чтобы не искать его каждый раз, т.к. событие scroll отстреливает часто

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if(scrollTop < $(window).scrollTop()){
    e.addClass('current');
  }else if(scrollTop > $(window).scrollTop()){
    e.removeClass('current');
  };
  scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

```css
body {height: 1000px}

.top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  height:20px; /* Добавил, что бы наглядно было */
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 99;
}
.top-bar.current {opacity: 0.5}
.top-bar.current:hover {opacity: 1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="top-bar">
</div>
```

Comment: Мб `-sb` переименовать на что-то без дефиса в начале? И в переменную загнать весь хедер, а не его класс.

Comment: @br3t, если это так принципиально, то вот

Comment: спасибо все классно, только когда вверх крутишь колесико оно почему то становиться активным

Comment: @duddeniska, то колёсико на мыши поломалось. У меня бывает крутишь и иногда вниз срабатывает

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 100) {
        $(".top-bar").addClass("top-bar-current");
    } else {
        $(".top-bar").removeClass("top-bar-current");
    }
});
```

```css
body{
    min-height: 2000px;
   background: #ddd;
}

.top-bar {
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 99;
}
.top-bar-current{
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.top-bar-current:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-bar">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда страница скролится, добавим класс, например, `scrolled`:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.top-bar').addClass('scrolled')
}
```

Определим его в css:

```
.top-bar.scrolled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Но если наведено мышью, вернем обратно 1:

```
.top-bar:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Вот и все, тестим:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.top-bar').addClass('scrolled')
  } else {
    $('.top-bar').removeClass('scrolled')
  }

})
```

```css
.top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 99;
  height: 20px;
}
.top-bar.scrolled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.top-bar:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.content {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-bar"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```